# r conditional standard deviation on 2 matrices

Tags: r, conditional-statements, standard-deviation

I am trying to calculate the conditional standard deviation of a matrix B (for every column) based on the values of matrix A.

```
#conditional function
foo<-function(x,y)
{
  out<-sd(y[abs(x)==1])
  return(out)
}

#create the matrix
A<-matrix(data=c(1,-1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1),nrow=5,ncol=2)
B<-matrix(data=c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),nrow=5,ncol=2)

#run for the first column
foo(A[,1],B[,1])

#run for both columns
apply(X=A, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x,y) foo(x,y), y=B)
```

the correct answer is 1.53 and 0.707 which I get when i run directly the foo individually for every column.

However, when i try to run both columns with apply I get this result 3.06 2.94.

Any idea how to change the apply in order to make it work cause I have a large matrix of assets (in xts object). Currently, I am using a for loop but I am sure it can be done with a more efficient way.

Thank you in advance,

Nikos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you're trying to pass a matrix (`B`) to your function `foo`, which is expecting two vectors (`x` and `y`).

You could try something like this instead:

```
sapply(1:ncol(A), function(i) sd(B[as.logical(abs(A[,i])),i]))

[1] 1.5275252 0.7071068
```

Which is basically just a loop...

Another approach would be if your `A` and `B` objects are dataframes, you can use `mapply`:

```
A <- as.data.frame(A)
B <- as.data.frame(B)
mapply(foo, A,B)

       V1        V2 
1.5275252 0.7071068
```

Benchmarking the two approaches, the `sapply` route is maybe twice as fast. I can imagine that this is because `sapply` is just taking a vector of integers as arguments and processing matrices whereas the `mapply` approach is taking dataframes as arguments (dataframes are slower than matrices and more information to pass the loop than just a single index value). Details:

```
Unit: microseconds
                                                             expr     min      lq  median       uq      max neval
 sapply(1:ncol(A), function(i) sd(B[as.logical(abs(A[, i])), i])) 101.997 110.080 113.929 118.5480 1515.319  1000
                                              mapply(foo, A2, B2) 191.292 200.529 207.073 215.1555 1707.380  1000
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer Thomas.

I am going to use the sapply function. I have 2 questions regarding some of your comments:

1) why do you have to define 1:ncol(A) in sapply? is it because you want to force B to change columns?

2) based on the comment for the loop, which would be a more efficient calculation? the sapply or mapply?

Thanks again

Comment: @user2493820 (1) `1:ncol(A)` is because this is a loop and that's just telling `sapply` which column numbers to work with in the two matrices. `1:ncol(B)` and `1:2` would produce the same result in this example. Regarding (2), see some benchmarking that I've added to the answer.